# Why C++14 Generic lambdas require auto in parameters specification?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I look at [Generic lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14#Generic_lambdas) and cant get it - why keep type declaration at all? why not 
`(x, y)`? If compiler vendors will have to support `(auto a, auto b)` Are there any problems supporting simple `(a, b)`?

Comment: Oh bother, I had made a nice message on the C++14 tag telling people not to use it yet. Anyway, as I recall from following the proposal, they initially proposed typeless parameters, but it was decided that it wasn't verbose enough.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned argumrents like " you need the lambda to have a particular signature which you don't control", "place unnamed arguments are routinely used is operator++" and "pass a special type as kind of a flag" are so rediculasly wrong...

Comment: @myWallJSON: That says more about your experience than anything else. E.g. the Windows API is full of places which will accept a stateless lambda (because of the implicit conversion to function pointer). And I obviously do NOT control the signatures in Windows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you are also allowed to leave out the parameter's name. If the compiler sees `(a,b)` and `a` and `b` are also valid types, what should that mean? `(a /*dummy_a*/, b /*dummy_b*/)` or `(auto a, auto b)`? With having to type `auto` explicitly, it is no longer ambiguous.

Comment: But if we leave out parameter's name how we can access it inside our lambda body? And If we can not, when do we need such functionality?

Comment: @myWallJSON You can't access such parameters and you need such functionality when you need the lambda to have a particular signature which you don't control. One place unnamed arguments are routinely used is `operator++ (int)`.

Comment: @myWallJSON For two reasons: Consistency (because you don't want special rules just here) and because for some functions, you just pass a parameter with a special type as kind of a flag, you don't actually use the value of the parameter itself. Especially useful when using templates, I think you can find many examples on SO.